# Xamarin ListView Height Issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In Xamarin, one of the ListView controller I have few items, Let's say after a filter operation I got 2 items.

Then again I filtered the list and let's say I got 20 Items.

However the problem is the list view height is not changed, it still shows the height as the previous two item height and the new items are only scroll able within that height.

Interestingly if I filter again the list view takes the entire height of the screen.

I did not put any height request for the ListView.

Please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide code C# and XAML if applicable.

Comment: The issue was in the stack layout, I need to set layout.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ideally I would suggest setting a fixed size when using a `ListView` so that your overall layout won't "jump" around. But if you must keep it dynamic you can use [`RequestLayout()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#requestLayout())

Comment: Dear Alex, Thanks for the answer, But I don't see this option in Xamarin.

Comment: call `YourListView.RequestLayout()` after you update your items set. This should be the same place where you call `NotifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I think in Xamarin I dont have that option of RequestLayout(). Sorry.

Comment: The issue was in the stack layout, I need to set `layout.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;`